how to decrypt and verify a nested JWT with binary payload
I have a nested JWT to decrypt and verify. The payload is binary (header, binary payload , signature, encrypted with the public key). So there is no claims to parse. I've been looking at available libraries. I've tried to use jose library. Here's what I've done:
t, e := jwt.ParseSignedAndEncrypted(input)
if e != nil{
    return e
}
parsed, err := t.Decrypt(key)

I'm not sure how to proceed from here. The samples I saw has the following:
claims := new(interface{})
err = parsed.Claims(verificationKey, &claims)

But I can't do this because my payload is binary. It doesn't contain any claims.
How do I proceed from here?
EDIT
As per @brits request. Here is a sample payload I have:
The JWE encrypted data I have is:
eyJhbGciOiJFQ0RILUVTK0EyNTZLVyIsImVuYyI6IkEyNTZHQ00iLCJlcGsiOnsia3R5IjoiRUMiLCJjcnYiOiJQLTI1NiIsIngiOiJaUV8tUHE0ajdaZ0E5QjhWT1VWOHFYRUV3NV9CeUN0TUxpYmtteDFVUk80IiwieSI6IlBxMDVNTENJZkx5S1cxRHYzdzlzSHVqUXItNE1SbzBQTWRRS3JPU2ZZcmcifSwia2lkIjoia2V5XzAwMSJ9.np31orHS_r03cZ5FpOHxhWMd9Wl5Diex5lwy5vEyoMQEcEcyxd5XFw.pCslcVa3-2Es9I69.9gN8lPDOBliq8CiZZwEaA_aO7o-wNPWQDJVSHcB0dxYcHuI2NiaEyZM9yH1jhw8BWu9WMoagqHKR2X0hPuTcJd_cq1_4QoZL0beTjeueu2u04ILtehcioLoUJtEg2utHoEau6fmWh-7R9SYUnrMwDmOSeaGSHNBrPFPKqx4XkRCZzvF572dWkGbQGm3NlP2H4kkf6RWReCldAYyImNVxXot0AG0MRHbHD6sKJf3q0poXsbmLiM0VfSK2aNTQmws4B08NfeUHy4fogEqhNEsCxQDhR6o44XF-tHoSmEsFXIPVqPndw8zL-2K9jau_cxYdk03oJBrATanx83xZ1luKIzK-MvOthNvBECBctf1YSVq2PX3mAF1PcyOs6ZBvO8L2OHQCe-lm6yPrpCl4wzP7xSryKHPn_IdBYunH7D1HaGJ-Zhm2XmJ3TRpu9V706amKuAg_hBt-4mwyGmDG0qx5ulkqwvmUzx5cqeVyymdQzNI4F7syDsf23hbWQWE43VTHBT2BsKkacgX9L-SS4XTYV2ZlVHGuDewr9VZS-kyCwo0OlMcjU8r8VSJ_F0NCHXmY4RYQw2H4nQgHM0JzcL_oJ2fY3dSZuMlortpmxYjBc940oqliuRfSXoQLTisoK5xrzgLJFY-OFlrFVMITjieziEs10TF1Ns2Ms8aPSC5kQhqme0xVpt1zwL1w8Ugo1wUerSqm_-2I4tU_MOeP9egXvujS9PXnc579l1PXKmceDr5raFI.PpzH8OA_wiiVvMtUu-pgOg
As you can see, this has 5 parts (as required for a JWE encrypted data). If you decrypt that payload we get:
eyJhbGciOiJSUzI1NiIsImtpZCI6ImtleV8wMDIifQ.AQIDBAU.pd5XWuvqkrinyjr2Fm2sgxkG2uxI5pjNRgFVTeYK_881uk1dVZMlWJqkNuzKs053EmIxDB4QpoQ4JwHeKtjShD_Lxyw8hbTbAlezFlsEoWgPKMzpoombEoQW0SxpCJW0PCvqqd6Y7N5m6B_XwP6kPT72MoWKyaVPe1j7O6-Kv1gdyOSmQbWbnzuMzGWp2jnur_8qdIm4gUoNBZeWmG0kbEvLJuIs0qkR-3JSB8ZBQ7S8G4Zw--BtupqhVaF_ZQz7UQhSBMo86rYJiUI3fgDg-dsnB3C8lE7jWshgHRzUCNDA43yiKJQ4as3oa8nBG-F4dpo3ZO5u7grb5hcpkuXYi6dy0F4uFZNKIH3_3yWaoRArvpMIABhyYL1vuEKjNB32p2z3ztmYO5ZDXEI5mSKazd4Lz8WSW5TtUsx2O5WtczSyzJugvbAzShBJxdwS_JzKtOpUOU61fMWrVBqeTIlSp3kJ0AKmsE2GWJ92c8cElW5jWBFnJ64HPi5YS7e1IUgC
Which has 3 parts as required by JWT. The payload here is: AQIDBAU
Which when base64 decode into binary you get:
00000001 00000010 00000011 00000100 00000101
which is just bytes {1,2,3,4,5}

rfc7519 states "JWTs encode claims to be transmitted as a JSON object" so if your payload has no claims, I'd question whether it's a JWT? Perhaps you could provide an example payload and the decrypted value (it sounds like you may just have encrypted binary data?).

What you call "binary" is actually a []byte array. That is what the Decrypt() function returns, the decrypted jwt token as plain text, but stored in a byte array. You can verify this by turning the byte array into a string and printing it out: string(parsed). Nothing is parsed yet at that point, only decrypted.

Thanks for that edit, makes more sense now. Was this encrypted with a test key that you can share? (easier if we we can use the data you provided when answering, and to do that we need to be able to decrypt it).

Solution is:
var payload interface{}
err = parsed.Decode(&payload, false)

In jose you can use decode function with verify_signature false. It allows you to get payload without any claims.

"verify_signature false" worries me. The data package I'm receiving is both signed and encrypted. I don't want it go without verification.
